# Custom task on Task Scheduler

Tags: joomla-4.x, plugin

I am trying to create a custom Joomla 4 task scheduler by creating plugin, which runs the custom task code.
I created the test plugin name plg_abc_def, but I don’t know how to link it with the Task Manager - from Select a Task Type I only see the same 9 initial types.
Thanks for Your help.

Comment: Can you post up the plugin that you have created so that we can see what you are trying to do and provide a more specific and useful answer for you.

Comment: Can you share some samples of your code along with what you have tried so far to get the plugin running?

Comment: Thanks for Your answers. I already found what's wrong. The plugin should be in the group "task" and should be put in the folder plugins/task. Thank You once more.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see where I can to post attachments in this forum.